# xampp 403 forbidden in a linux server

Tags: apache, remote-access, lampp

i want to setup xampp server in a linux redhat server. The server is running.
When i try to curl/wget a content in a htdocs folder, 403 forbidden error given.

content of /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf file -

```
#<IfDefine PHP4>
#LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
#</IfDefine>
#<IfDefine PHP7>
#LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
#</IfDefine>

# We will enable it by default
#<IfDefine PHP>
   LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
#</IfDefine>

LoadModule perl_module        modules/mod_perl.so

Alias /phpmyadmin "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"

# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>

# since LAMPP 1.0RC1
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4

XBitHack on

# since 0.9.8 we've mod_perl
<IfModule mod_perl.c>
        AddHandler perl-script .pl
        PerlHandler ModPerl::PerlRunPrefork
        PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
        PerlSendHeader On
</IfModule>

# demo for mod_perl responsehandler
#PerlModule Apache::CurrentTime
#</Location>

# AcceptMutex sysvsem is default but on some systems we need this
# thanks to jeff ort for this hint
#AcceptMutex flock
#LockFile /opt/lampp/logs/accept.lock

# this makes mod_dbd happy - oswald, 02aug06
# mod_dbd doesn't work in Apache 2.2.3: getting always heaps of "glibc detected *** corrupted double-linked list" on shutdown - oswald, 10sep06
#DBDriver sqlite3
```

I modified the file with all granted.

vhosts file -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
ServerName chabot-test.banglalink.net
</VirtualHost>
```